# Getting flattened list of all values in dictionary

Tags: python

I have python dictionary like this:

```
d = {1:['x','y'], 2: ['a','b']}
```

I want to get all the values of dictionary.
Doing

```
d.values()
```

gives me

```
[['x', 'y'], ['a', 'b']]
```

But I would like to have something like this -

```
['x', 'y', 'a', 'b']
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So, you want to "flatten" a list? There should be more than just a few questions about it on SO

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: Can't give you `[['x', 'y'], ['a', 'b']]` as there's no *'x'* (or *'y'*) in `d`.